# Robolectric idleMainLooper explanation

Tags: android, shadow, robolectric

Robolectric `idleMainLooper()` I want to know specifically the usage of this function and its functionality.

```
ShadowLooper.idleMainLooper();
```

If I use a line as above what is likely to happen?

Answer (score 1):

This is what `idle` does according to [docs](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLooper.html#idle--).

> Causes Runnables that have been scheduled to run immediately to
>   actually run. Does not advance the scheduler's clock

You would use this on a `Looper` that you have *shadowed*. So `idleMainLooper` will just do exactly that on the main looper. Code is [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/ed57c3393646ca79bc69d4958feeca583c0850a6/robolectric-shadows/shadows-core/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLooper.java#L143-L145)